# ASP Clássico & MySQL - Descobrir em que página o registro X se encontra

Tags: mysql, asp, lógica

Estou com um problema que eu creio ser mais de lógica do que da linguagem em si, mas se conseguirem responder em `ASP` Clássico já ajuda bastante.

Estou necessitando criar uma função, onde dado um registro X, e uma quantidade de registros por página, indique em que página o registro aparece.

Exemplo de resultset:

```
Página 1  |  Página 2  | Página 3 |
id: 155   |  Id: 863   | Id: 1024 |
Id: 154   |  Id: 864   | Id: 1023 |
```

A idéia é criar uma função em que eu passasse pra ela os parâmetros de consulta, e o id necessário, e ela me retornasse em que página o ID apareceria.

No caso, se eu passasse o id: 863, ela me retornaria a página 02. Se fosse o 154, a página 1 e por aí vai.

Agradeço desde já a atenção.

Comment: Mas onde estão as referências página x id? Elas pulam número ou não?

Comment: Quais seriam esses parâmetros?

Comment: Apresente a sua query e o script que está usando para a paginação